# Horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, wordpress, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

Is it possible to have both for one site while using the anchor tags?

I have already set up a website that does horizontal scrolling for each parent page. Some of these parent pages has child pages in sections that I will like to have scroll vertically to on that page with a sub menu on top.

I know I will have to use Javascript for this, but I was wondering what I need to do in the function to differentiate the horizontal scrolling for the parent pages with the vertical scrolling for the parent page's sub sections.

Comment: Are there any visual examples that can be given for what you are wanting to do?

Comment: Perhaps something like [Scroll path](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/) is what you're looking for?

Comment: @summea http://themeforest.net/item/reversal-horizontal-one-page-wordpress-theme/4974890 this an example of a horizontal site. But within each page I want to have subnavigation that will scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Scroll Converter?

https://github.com/koggdal/scroll-converter